# BMW ticking noise

Tags: engine, noise, bmw

I have a BMW 130i N52 motor and the car is making a constant ticking noise whilst idiling and accelarating. The car also has a slight loss in power and rough on the idle. Hydraulic lifters have just been changed as well,
Any ideas,

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are so many things this could be from air leak to bad fuel. Unfortunately, you have not given us enough detail to be able to really help you. If major maintenance has recently been performed, I would suggest taking back to the garage that did the work and have them make it right.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked for exhaust leaks? Look for soot traces at the head where the exhaust manifold attaches.

Comment: Ticking can be injector noise, and spark plugs being worn can affect that and the power and idle. Clogged air intake or filter also.

Comment: Is it a regular ticking, or does it sound like it goes off on one cylinder? Mine does this when the oil has settled. Have you tried holding > 3k RPM for more than 5 minutes? This will help flood the valve trains with oil.